# Using curl in QProcess

Tags: qt, curl, qprocess

I have a problem which is quite similar to my last question [Ssh command from Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634876/ssh-command-from-qt). But I cannot understand what is wrong with one of the arguments that I pass to cUrl in QProcess. The code is:

```
  QStringList params;
  const double timeout = 8.0;
  params.append("'--connect-timeout " + QString("%1").arg(timeout) + "'");
  params.append("-T" + obj->absoluteFilePath());
  params.append("ftp://" + m_host + "/inbox" + m_logsPath + obj->name());
  m_process->start("curl", params);
```

But it always gives me an error: curl: option --connect-timeout 8: is unknown.
And again when I run it from the command line everything is fine. I understand that I have an error while passing argumnets, but I can't find it. Thanx a lot!

Comment: It should be `params.append(QString("--connect-timeout %1").arg(timeout) );` instead, I believe.

Comment: Why not use `QNetworkAccessManager` for this? It's built into Qt and includes FTP support.

Comment: @MrEricSir Yes, thanx for your notice. I wanted to use it. But I need do upload, download and delete files from ftp server. And when I serached through the net the only option that I found about deleting files was using cUrl from QProcess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  QStringList params;
  const double timeout = 8.0;
  params.append("--connect-timeout");
  params.append(QString("%1").arg(timeout));
  params.append("-T" + obj->absoluteFilePath());
  params.append("ftp://" + m_host + "/inbox" + m_logsPath + obj->name());
  m_process->start("curl", params);
```

With your version you are passing something like

```
curl "'--connect-timeout <timeout>'" #curl sees 1 arg
```

With mine it is:

```
curl "--connect-timeout" "<timeout>" #curl sees 2 arg, as it is generally the case when executing it from a shell
```

Keep in mind that `start()` will not split each `params` element further.

Comment: Thanx so much for your answer! But it didn't help. The error is still the same.

Comment: Wow. I was very mistaken. When I used your example I forgot to remove the space at the end of "--connect-timeout " in my code. So after removing it it works fine. Thanx a lot!